# Can't get ParseDown to parse contents of a file

Tags: php, markdown, parsedown

I am fairly new to PHP. I am trying to get my code to read the content of a Markdown file based on the content of GET attribute "pgid", and then output it. 
This:

```
print Parsedown::instance()->text("Testing *Markdown* with **Parsedown**")
```

results in the output

> Testing *Markdown* with **Parsedown**

But this:

```
print (Parsedown::instance()->text(readfile("./".$_GET['pgid'].".md")));
```

with `?pgid=about` and the content of `about.md` being `Testing *Markdown* with **Parsedown**`, the output is

> Testing *Markdown* with **Parsedown**
>   39

I am unsure why  I can get all of the parts to work separately, but not together.

Comment: Because `readfile` writes directly to the output buffer, instead of _returning_ the file content it has read. Replace it with `file_get_contents`.

Comment: @CBroe I've now changed it and that worked. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's `readfile()` does not *return* file contents, it *outputs* them.

What your code does, is basically this:

```
print readfile($filename); // The print() here is implied by readfile itself.
print (Parsedown::instance()->text(80));
```

Where 80 is the number of bytes read from the file.

Instead of `readfile()`, you'll probably want to use [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents), which does return the contents of the file.

Comment: I understand now, thanks! I'm coming from python where read() returns the file contents. Thanks for your help.